# Convert xlsx to pdf using Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to use Laravel Excel (maatwebsite) to build a simple function to upload an Excel file and convert it to pdf straight away.

I'm looking for something like that (conceptual obviously) :

```
$file = $request->file('my_excel');
$excel_object = Excel::import($file);
$excel_object->export('/my/storage/path/my_file.pdf');
```

Can anyone please explain how to achieve or point me to a relevant example ?

thanks a lot

Adam

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to use a package like "Html2Pdf". You should make a blade file with your data, render it to HTML and convert it to pdf.